# What the server can count to 1 sec. Whit loops PHP?

Tags: php, loops

**What the server can count to 1 sec. Whit loops PHP ?**

How do i make a loop to say, echo all the numbers it can in 1 sec ?

Comment: Your question seems to be a little short on information, please consider to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";

    //sleep for 1 second
    sleep(1);
    //start again
    echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
    //sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(5);
    //start again
    echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
?>
```

sleep() method will delay code execution by specified amount.
You can also add sleep(1); inside the loop, and it will wait 1s between iterations

Comment: if i would make it with a loop, and like how many numbers can it echo in 1 sec, how would you do that ?

Comment: This loop will keep executing for 1 sec and then it will break:
        $start = microtime(true);
        $limit = 1;  // number of seconds

        for ($i=1 ; $i >= 1 ; $i++) {
            if (microtime(true) - $start >= $limit) {
                break;
            }
            echo $i .'<br>';
        }
        die;